# A plain Vowelburger™ riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>You can find other Vowelburgers™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion)</sup>*

---

I ordered 5 plain Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | back |
| E | snake |
| I | orchestra |
| O | ruin |
| U | impose |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger comes with

> A **P** bun and a **T** bun

I think they are

> A - PAT, like *pat on the back*
>  E - PET
>  I - PIT, where the orchestra sits
>  O - POT, as in *gone to pot*
>  U - PUT

Comment: This was waaaaaay to fast. rot13(cng ba gur onpx) follows the same rule as rot13(tbar gb cbg)

Comment: @melfnt Ah, yes, but rot13(cbg vf nyfb n flabalz bs ehva juvyr cng vf abg n flabalz bs onpx). No matter, in the end you get to define the rules so there is no quibble, will edit my answer.